# Is there a site where I can look for potential collaborators on an academic project that I'm pursuing all by myself?

Tags: collaboration, website, social-media

I'm working on an academic project, and after getting a few results by myself, I'm a bit stuck. Currently, I'm not affiliated to any university or company, and also since I switched from my PhD topic to postdoc topic to topics in which I worked in companies, I don't have a known network whom I can connect with for a discussion.

So I'm looking for a website(s), where I can post a question/request like: *"I'm working on project XYZ, and if someone with an expertise is interested, I'd be glad to share my draft and initiate a collaboration."* I'll of course either take them as collaborators or acknowledge their contribution. Any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately this is a "shopping question" and so is off-topic here. If you have a local university, you could start there rather than online.

Comment: What field are you working in?

Comment: @NathanS. High dimensional statistics/machine learning, specially something called "distance concentration."  This is also used in the mathematical theory of database systems/database theory. It's related to this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Jonathan_Goldstein4/publication/2845566_When_Is_Nearest_Neighbor_Meaningful/links/09e4150b3eb298bf21000000/When-Is-Nearest-Neighbor-Meaningful.pdf

Comment: @Buffy Are you sure it is a shopping question? Looking for a place where the poster can find help surely is, but asking about general sites where anyone can find collaborators may be an interesting question for many people and could yield a useful list of sites and communities.

Answer (score 4):

I know you're looking for a web site, but I think you're unlikely to find one. With typical web anonymity it's hard to build trust and have open conversations. The number of people qualified and interested in working on a certain problems is often quite small, and the chance of them all being on the same web site is then even smaller.

So, this is typically one role of conferences and workshops, although this can really depend on the field. Luckily, these days (this may change back in two years) most of these are happening online in very accessible formats, so it might be much easier than normal to participate.

Workshops tend to be a slightly less formal presentations of work - if you can find a workshop where you can present you might find others who are interested. Similarly, if you find others presenting at a workshop or conference, you might be able to discuss collaboration opportunities.

A few weeks ago ICML included online socials where people could meet up and talk about proposed topics. This sort of thing could have worked really well for your purposes, and I'm sure future ML conferences will continue to have these types of meetups.

Of course, typical social interaction rules apply - not everyone will be willing and/or interested in collaborating.